# How to handle a shutdown request in Java

Tags: java, docker, jvm

I assume Java applications receive some sort of shutdown request when, for instance, an OS is trying to reboot. I would like to have some control over how my applications handle these requests. But, I do not know where to start. Some questions I have are:

Do all shutdown requests come from the JVM?
Are the requests different for containers, VMs, and bare metal OSs? I am especially interested on how this is handled inside a docker container.
And, of course, what libraries can I use to handle these requests?

It would be wonderful if someone could point to a resource where this is covered in depth, besides the raw documentation, such as a book or online course (does not have to be free). Although, a link to the documentation will definitely be appreciated as well. Thanks!

Update:
I know I need to be able handle an event like the power cord being yanked.
However, when I ask my Windows machine to shutdown, sometimes a window pops up saying something like "waiting for these application to close". So, I assume the OS tells the applications to shut themselves down before forcing them to stop. Is this an incorrect assumption?

What I want to accomplish is for the app to log information or update a database before shutdown.

I will take a look at the `addShutdownHook`. Thanks again!

Comment: what do you mean by shutdown request. Are you asking, is there way to check, if application was abruptly closed ?

Comment: This depends totally on how the OS and/or container interacts with running processes during shutdown.  You cannot count on ***anything*** specific happening.  You may get a JVM shutdown that you can trap via a shutdown hook, but more likely the JVM just _disappears_ without your code receiving any notice.

Comment: Thanks, Jim. This is the type of info I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a shutdown hook via the `Runtime` class. Mind you, these are not guaranteed to run, such as if someone yanks the power cord.

Refer [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread))

Comment: Can the downvoters care to explain why was this downvoted?

Comment: This may be my best option, but I will give the rest of the community time to respond. Thanks, Lev!